# python raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

Tags: python, json

I am trying to pull data from fulcrum app using following code

```
import requests

url = "https://api.fulcrumapp.com/api/v2/query"

querystring = {"q":"SELECT * FROM \"Inspection Report\"","format":"json","headers":"true","metadata":"false","arrays":"false","page":"1","per_page":"200000"}

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "X-ApiToken": "*************"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

#print(response.text)

item_dict = json.loads(response.text)
len(item_dict['rows'])
```

But I get following error

```
>>> item_dict = json.loads(response.text)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 80459 column 1 (char 200665199)
```

I am expecting to have more than 100K records in the `response.text`. But just to validate it I am trying to get a length here. If i run query with limit `SELECT * FROM \"Inspection Report\" limit 3` it produces output without any error.

Update : Tried this to see what is in the data.

```
response.text[200665180:200665210]
'n_no":null},\n\n!!!!!!!!\n{"messa'
```

Comment: Can you please try to check what is at `response.text[200665198:200665200]` and share it

Comment: updated with output

Comment: I think the problem may be with those `!!!` as json decoder may not be able to decode them.

Comment: Try using smaller value for `per_page` property in request

Comment: `"per_page":"60000"` did work.

Comment: Generally `json.loads()` method handles UTF8 encoded data natively but sometimes it could also be incompatible character encoding. The error tells you that you are getting `None` somewhere instead of string.